# First time Controlled Temp Fermentation, May have put yeast to sleep

Tags: fermentation, yeast, secondary-fermentation

Just made a falconer's flight/citra IPA. Well, for the first time, I have a free cooler to do a controlled temp fermentation. I had the cooler set to 50 degrees to help cool the wort before pitching. I pitched, and fell asleep before turning the cooler up to 63 degrees like a moron. I woke up to no action in the air lock and no movement in the beer. I got the temp up slowly (it took all day) and now it's in its controlled environment at 63 degrees. This morning i woke up there were a few tiny yeast rafts on top. My questions are:

1- Does the yeast rafts indicate the yeast waking up? Will fermentation kick off soon or am i out of luck?

2- The wort sat at around 50 degrees for 12 hours and has been slowly warming up for around 30 hours at the desired temp. Should i expect off flavors? Will it be alright since it was sealed and at a low temp?

Answer (score 1):

**should be ok**

1) It sounds like it just has more lag time from the cool temp. It should kick off soon.

2) actually the opposite, the colder temp has slowed the growth phase so the yeast will produce less esters.

Side note:

There's not much risk in thermal shock going warm to cool. Cold to hot is what can burst cell walls.